# Validation curve unlike SKLearn sample

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, plotting, matplotlib

I'm trying to implement the validation curve based on [this](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/plot_validation_curve.html) SKLearn tutorial. On the site, it shows how based on the parameters the model goes from under- to overfitted, finding the optimal parameter in the middle. My implementation you can see below, but my curve is weird - the train and test scores seem not do differ at all. What does this mean? Am I doing something incorrectly? My inputs `X` and `y` are shaped (266531, 23) and (266531,).

The curve looks like this:

[image: The training and validation scores completely overlap]

And my code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.learning_curve import validation_curve
import psutil

np.random.seed(0)

X, y = prepareDataframeX.values, prepareDataframeY.values.ravel()
indices = np.arange(y.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
X, y = X[indices], y[indices]

param_range = np.arange(1, 41, 2)
train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced'), X, y, param_name="max_depth", cv=10, 
    param_range=param_range,n_jobs=psutil.cpu_count(),
    scoring="accuracy")

train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
plt.title("Validation Curve with DecisionTree")
plt.xlabel("max_depth")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.ylim(0.0, 1.1)
plt.plot(param_range, train_scores_mean, label="Training score",
             color="r")
plt.plot(param_range, test_scores_mean, label="Cross-validation score",
             color="g")

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.xticks(param_range)
plt.show()
```

**UPDATE**

A comment suggested I made `X` and `y` identical. This is not the case. What else might cause the validation curve to look like this? I don't think it's right.
[image]

Comment: quick note: if you want to use all available CPUs, just set `n_jobs=-1`

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly your code just with *digits* data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.learning_curve import validation_curve
import psutil
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

np.random.seed(0)

# X, y = prepareDataframeX.values, prepareDataframeY.values.ravel()


digits = load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target

indices = np.arange(y.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
X, y = X[indices], y[indices]

param_range = np.arange(1, 41, 2)
train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced'), X, y, param_name="max_depth", cv=10, 
    param_range=param_range,n_jobs=psutil.cpu_count(),
    scoring="accuracy")

train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.title("Validation Curve with DecisionTree")
plt.xlabel("max_depth")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.ylim(0.0, 1.1)
#plt.fill_between(param_range, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std, train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.2, color="r")
plt.plot(param_range, train_scores_mean, label="Training score",
             color="r")
#plt.fill_between(param_range, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std, test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.2, color="g")
plt.plot(param_range, test_scores_mean, label="Cross-validation score",
             color="g")

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.xticks(param_range)
plt.savefig('DSSE.jpg')
plt.show()
```

And this is the result:

[image]

So whatever the problem is, it's in your data that you didn't explain how you created it. Either double check it or post it here so your question can be answered. I assume somewhere in data preparation you made X and Y identical by mistake.

Comment: I'll update the post: X and y are NOT identical. Any other things that might cause this?

Comment: @Kasra Manshaei . Could you please let me know how to plot validation curve for class weight?

Comment: @Ebrahimi What do you mean by Class Weight?

Comment: @KasraManshaei Thanks. In your code: class_weight='balanced' but I want to plot validation curve if class_weight will be: param_range2=[{ 0:1, 1:6 },{ 0:1, 1:4 },{ 0:1, 1:5.5 },{ 0:1, 1:4.5 },{ 0:1, 1:5 }]. However, TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'is produced.